# Tabs with counter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have to create a tabbedpage similar to whatsapp.
I don't know how to visualize the number next to the title. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87756/tabbedpage-icon-next-to-title

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting NuGet Package which can solve your problem:
[xamarin-forms-tab-badge](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge)

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: ok but I can't set the size of the badge.

it's too small.

the properties are:

  public static BindableProperty BadgeTextProperty;
         public static BindableProperty BadgeColorProperty;
         public static BindableProperty BadgeTextColorProperty;
         public static BindableProperty BadgeFontProperty;
         public static BindableProperty BadgePositionProperty;

Comment: font size is not supported yet on android   https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge#badge-font-attributes